# heroku nodejs app api url reflecting localhost

Tags: heroku, deployment, mean-stack

After deploying my mean app to heroku, everything works fine, page is displayed as it should, but when i tried to login as user and checked chrome network tab i realised that the request url is to Request URL: http://localhost:4444/graphql.

please all help / advice will save my day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you write the url request in your code ? If you tried to request the application you deploy on Heroku you should use environnement variable to set the url.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I had defined uri for apollo initiation in the angular app which was the unfortunate cause of the problems